# Place a span depending on its div

Tags: html, css

I have a succession of div which each contains a span (visible or not due to some javascript event).

I just don't get why the visible span can't be placed right at the bottom of its parent div, instead of being placed at the bottom of all the div.

Here's the fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/3tqgyaff/5/

```css
.layer {
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    /* padding: 2px; */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.5px;
    border-color: whitesmoke;
    width:75px;
    height: 75px;
}

.listLayer {
    bottom:5px;
    left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.layerChosen {
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.5px;
    border-color: whitesmoke;
    width:75px;
    height: 75px;
}

.layerHovered {
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.5px;
    border-color: whitesmoke;
    width:75px;
    height: 75px;
}

.layerHovered:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,696969+100&0+46,0.65+80 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(48,48,48,0) 46%, rgba(84,84,84,0.65) 80%, rgba(105,105,105,0.65) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(48,48,48,0) 46%,rgba(84,84,84,0.65) 80%,rgba(105,105,105,0.65) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(48,48,48,0) 46%,rgba(84,84,84,0.65) 80%,rgba(105,105,105,0.65) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#a6696969',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}


.layerChosen:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,696969+100&0+46,0.65+80 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(48,48,48,0) 46%, rgba(84,84,84,0.65) 80%, rgba(105,105,105,0.65) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(48,48,48,0) 46%,rgba(84,84,84,0.65) 80%,rgba(105,105,105,0.65) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(48,48,48,0) 46%,rgba(84,84,84,0.65) 80%,rgba(105,105,105,0.65) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#a6696969',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

.layerName {
    bottom: 2px;
    text-shadow: darkgray;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: smaller;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 2px;
}

.listLayer {
    position : absolute;
}

.layerNameHover {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="listLayer">
    <div class="layer" id="layer_grey">
      <span class="layerNameHover" style="visibility:hidden;" >grey</span>
  </div>
  <div class="layer" id="layer_cmap" >
    <span class="layerNameHover" style="visibility:hidden;">cmap</span>
  </div>
  <div class="layer layerHovered" id="layer_stamen">
    <span class="layerNameHover">stamen</span>
  </div>
  <div class="layerChosen"><span class="layerName" >bright</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It *is* at the bottom, it's just that its parent div is stacked on top of the next div.

Comment: Remove pictures, remove extra unformation like react ids, remove inline styles in the fiddle.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Qwertiy I need that inline styles because it is how I define my div due to onMouseOver  and onMouseOut

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude How am I supposed to seek help in CSS then?

Comment: In stackoverflow, you need to explain what do you want and what you have actually, and provide a working example. This question have a poor quality due the rules of stackoverflow. You can improve the question to avoid this will be closed.

Comment: @So4ne, provide minimal reprodusable example. You even have no js tag on you question, so why do you care about some hendlers? The are not related to this question. And it contains nothing about fact that inline styles have to be permanent. So just simpliify you example.

Comment: @Qwertiy ok thx for advice, I updated the example. You're right I did'nt get that wasn't important.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thanks for the advice, I'm searching for a better explanation of my problem. As CSS is not my predilection, if it doesn't work, then it doesn't work :) I just can't find how to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `position: absolute` on the inner `span` where its parent `div` haven't `position: relative`.

Update these CSS rules like this

```
.layer {
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    /* padding: 2px; */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.5px;
    border-color: whitesmoke;
    width:75px;
    height: 75px;
    position : relative;              /* added */
}

.layerChosen {
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.5px;
    border-color: whitesmoke;
    width:75px;
    height: 75px;
    position : relative;              /* added */
}

.layerNameHover,                      /* added this class to the rule */
.layerName {
    bottom: 2px;
    text-shadow: darkgray;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: smaller;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 2px;
}
```

Sample

```css
.layer {
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    /* padding: 2px; */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.5px;
    border-color: whitesmoke;
    width:75px;
    height: 75px;
    position : relative;
}

.listLayer {
    bottom:5px;
    left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.layerChosen {
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.5px;
    border-color: whitesmoke;
    width:75px;
    height: 75px;
    position : relative;
}

.layerHovered {
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.5px;
    border-color: whitesmoke;
    width:75px;
    height: 75px;
}

.layerHovered:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,696969+100&0+46,0.65+80 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(48,48,48,0) 46%, rgba(84,84,84,0.65) 80%, rgba(105,105,105,0.65) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(48,48,48,0) 46%,rgba(84,84,84,0.65) 80%,rgba(105,105,105,0.65) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(48,48,48,0) 46%,rgba(84,84,84,0.65) 80%,rgba(105,105,105,0.65) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#a6696969',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}


.layerChosen:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,696969+100&0+46,0.65+80 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(48,48,48,0) 46%, rgba(84,84,84,0.65) 80%, rgba(105,105,105,0.65) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(48,48,48,0) 46%,rgba(84,84,84,0.65) 80%,rgba(105,105,105,0.65) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(48,48,48,0) 46%,rgba(84,84,84,0.65) 80%,rgba(105,105,105,0.65) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#a6696969',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

.layerNameHover,
.layerName {
    bottom: 2px;
    text-shadow: darkgray;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: smaller;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 2px;
}

.listLayer {
    position : absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="listLayer" data-reactid=".0.0.2.1.3">
    <div class="layer" id="layer_grey" style="visibility: visible; background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/75/75/abstract/1/');" data-reactid=".0.0.2.1.3.0:0">
      <span class="layerNameHover" style="visibility:hidden;" data-reactid=".0.0.2.1.3.0:0.0">grey</span>
  </div>
  <div class="layer" id="layer_cmap" style="visibility: visible; background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/75/75/abstract/2/');" data-reactid=".0.0.2.1.3.0:1">
    <span class="layerNameHover" style="visibility:hidden;" data-reactid=".0.0.2.1.3.0:1.0">cmap</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="layer layerHovered" id="layer_stamen" style="visibility: visible; background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/75/75/abstract/3/');" data-reactid=".0.0.2.1.3.0:3">
  
    <span class="layerNameHover" style="visibility: visible;position: absolute;" data-reactid=".0.0.2.1.3.0:3.0">stamen</span>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="layerChosen" style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/75/75/abstract/4/');width:75px;height:75px;" data-reactid=".0.0.2.1.3.1:2">        <span class="layerName" data-reactid=".0.0.2.1.3.1:2.0">bright</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Position property is something I don't get. Just put all in absolute :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.layerHovered {
  position: relative;
}

.layerNameHover {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```